# How do I register a Hibernate saveUpdate listener when using Spring's AnnoationSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to add a custom save event listener for hibernate.  My goal is to have hibernate set the last update and created timestamp values on certain entities.  I have read from other posts that JPA annotations will do it but if you are using a Hibernate Session then you need to extend DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.  I did this and it hasn't worked.  Every example I see is using a hibernate config file.  My sessionFactory is configured with Spring.

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="myDataSource"/>
    </property>     
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>           
         <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>    
         <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
       </props>
    </property> 
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.mypackages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="eventListeners">
        <map>
            <entry key="save-update">
                <ref local="saveEventListener"  />
            </entry>

        </map>
    </property>     
</bean>
    <bean id="saveEventListener" class="com.mypackage.event.SaveOrUpdateDateListener" />
```

I set a breakpoint and it doesn't go through the listener.  My last updated and created fields are not being set in the database.

Comment: A coworker of mine found an easy fix for this and it was to change the map key from "save-update" to just "save".   This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with the similar issue and finally resolved.
I have a base pojo with properties for Auditing , Every entity extends this base pojo. on call to save or update, the methods of Event Listeners get triggered where I update the entity with auditing information.

@Component

```
public class EntitySaveListener implements PersistEventListener, MergeEventListener,    
PreInsertEventListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(EntitySaveListener.class);

@Autowired
private LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory;

public EntitySaveListener() {
    logger.info("EntitySaveListener created");
}

public void onPersist(PersistEvent event) throws HibernateException {
    if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext() != null
            && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        if (principal != null && principal instanceof V2VUserDetails) {
            User user = ((V2VUserDetails) principal).getUser();
            if (event.getObject() instanceof ModificationTracker &&
            user != null) {
                ModificationTracker entity = (ModificationTracker) event.getObject();
                entity.setCreatedDate(new Date());
                entity.setCreatedBy(user);
                entity.setLastUpdated(new Date());
                entity.setLastUpdatedBy(user);
            }
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public void onPersist(PersistEvent event, Map arg1)
        throws HibernateException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onMerge(MergeEvent event) throws HibernateException {
    if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext() != null
            && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null) {
        Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        if (principal != null && principal instanceof V2VUserDetails) {
            User user = ((V2VUserDetails) principal).getUser();
            if (event.getEntity() instanceof ModificationTracker
                    && user != null) {
                ModificationTracker entity = (ModificationTracker) event
                        .getEntity();
                entity.setLastUpdated(new Date());
                entity.setLastUpdatedBy(user);
            }
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public void onMerge(MergeEvent arg0, Map arg1) throws HibernateException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public boolean onPreInsert(PreInsertEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}